# Crystal Reports barcode Code 128 with C#

Tags: c#, barcode-printing

I am really confused about printing and reading barcodes. I want to generate `Code 128` barecode using C#. Using Crystal Reports I found two ways to this:

- by adding dll files
- by using barcode Code 128 font

However I am looking to do this in my own application, not Crystal Reports.

I want to know what the difference between them?
Is there any problem by using the font one since it is more simple and do not any add file-ons to my project?

Finally anyone can give me a link to download barcode Code 128 font  **(FREE)**

Comment: Does it have to be a font or could it also generate a barcode image?

Comment: no it not necessary to be a font

Answer (score 1):

The thing about Code128 is that you can not just use a font and go for it (like it's the case for CODE39 for example). Why?

1. You need to add start/stop codes.
2. There are three subsets, A, B AND C which can be chosen and mixed within a barcode. They differ in the characters they can represent (for example: Subset C can only contain an even number of **numbers**, subset A can not contain small letters, etc.). You need to know what you want to encode.
3. You need to calculate a checksum.
4. Some of the "ASCII codes" for the symbologies are outside the printable area of the normal charsets.

Result: You really need a piece of software to "encode" the barcode.

Example: The software needs to convert

```
Hello User
```

into

```
<STARTB>Hello User<CHECKSUM><STOPCODE>
```

Or the number

```
0815
```

would have to be turned into

```
<STARTC>(/<CHECKSUM><STOPCODE>
```

You can, of course, use a ready-made library. However: If you [search for a description of Code 128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) you will be very easily able to implement it yourself. Usually you'll end up with an image.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this project has really helped me out with barcodes; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20823/Barcode-Image-Generation-Library.

It supports a decent amount of encodings and is fairly easy to use

```
                string value = "12345678";
                TYPE encoding = TYPE.CODE128;

                var barcode = new Barcode(value, encoding);
                barcode.IncludeLabel = true; //We want to display the value below the image.
                Image image = barcode.Encode(encoding, value, 300, 100);
                //Handle the image here...
```

Although it is not a font it does return an image like this

[image]

which could be printed or handled however you wish.

Comment: i had take a look about that project before posting here but i don't want standalone software what I really wont is to handle this issue as part of my over all project within the windows form need to generate barcode according to the data entered within the textboxs